# Is there any case where we can't solve a gamma distribution problem by switching to the incomplete version?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I have been learning about the gamma distribution and the book exercises are usually solved by directly integrating, however I found it more convenient to transform my gamma function into an incomplete gamma function and getting the answer from the table, is there any cases where I can't do that and I will have to integrate directly?

Comment: I would have thought using the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) (with a table or computer) is the same thing as integrating over an interval

Comment: so better just go the easy way I guess